# Evil key bindings with evil-define-key do opposite of what I want?

Tags: key-bindings, evil

Below is the entirety of my Evil key bindings in `init.el`:

```
(evil-define-key 'normal 'global (kbd "SPC") (make-sparse-keymap))
(evil-define-key 'normal 'global (kbd "SPC TAB") #'ivy-switch-buffer)
(evil-define-key 'normal 'Info-mode-map (kbd "SPC") (make-sparse-keymap))
(evil-define-key 'normal 'Info-mode-map (kbd "SPC SPC") #'Info-scroll-up)
```

The end result of this is as follows:

- In `Emacs-Lisp` mode, `SPC TAB` is bound to `ivy-switch-buffer`; this is expected.
- In `Emacs-Lisp` mode, `SPC SPC` is bound to `Info-scroll-up`; this is unexpected.
- In `Info` mode, `SPC TAB` is undefined; this is unexpected.
- In `Info` mode, `SPC SPC` is bound to `Info-scroll-up`; this is expected.

It seems to me (in one sentence) that the global config is not global and the local config is global. This is the opposite of what I would expect.

The `Info-scroll-up` binding is defined on `Info-mode-map` and has effect even when `Info` mode is not active. Why?

The `ivy-switch-buffer` binding is defined globally, but does not work when I am in `Info` mode. Not only does it not work, but it is undefined. It's not that `SPC TAB` has been replaced by another command, `SPC TAB` is undefined (and `SPC` is a prefix key). Why?

I can't form any mental model of why Evil / Emacs is behaving this way. Why is it behaving this way?

Comment: Please look at the Emacs manual on keybindings, and then the evil manual on how to do keybindings in evil globally and in specific modes.

Comment: @Dan I have read all 11 pages of the Evil manual twice.

Answer (score 1):

This works as expected:

```
(evil-define-key 'normal 'global (kbd "SPC") (make-sparse-keymap))
(evil-define-key 'normal 'global (kbd "SPC TAB") #'ivy-switch-buffer)
(evil-define-key 'normal Info-mode-map (kbd "SPC") (make-sparse-keymap))
(evil-define-key 'normal Info-mode-map (kbd "SPC SPC") #'Info-scroll-up)
```

Notice that `Info-mode-map` is not quoted like it was in the original question.

The `evil-define-key` docs mention you can pass `'global'` or `'local` as the second argument. I'm not sure what it does if you give it some other quoted value like I was doing, but now that I'm calling `evil-define-key` correctly it works the way I would expect.