# Pass keymap as an argument to a function

Tags: evil

I have the hard time straggling of passing elisp keymap to a custom function. I expect that after major mode has loaded (in my case it's clojure-mode) my new keybindings become available, but they don't:

```lisp
;;; Settings.
(straight-use-package 'paredit)

(defun my/shared-lisp-mode-hook ()
  (require 'paredit)
  (my/vim-paredit-init clojure-mode-map))

;;; Clojure.
(straight-use-package 'cider)

;; This doesn't work.
(defun my/vim-paredit-init (map)
  (evil-define-key 'normal map (kbd "<localleader>r") #'paredit-raise-sexp))

;; This works, but not what I want.
;; (defun my/vim-paredit-init (map)
;;   (evil-define-key 'normal clojure-mode-map (kbd "<localleader>r") #'paredit-raise-sexp))


(defun my/clojure-mode-hook ()
  (my/shared-lisp-mode-hook))
  
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook #'my/clojure-mode-hook)
```

I know I miss something conceptual and trivial, but couldn't come up to any, but duplicating paredit key bindings for all major modes: elisp, clojure, which I want to avoid...

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: There's too much code in your question, and not enough specification of what exactly you want to do. Can you provide a minimal example showing what you've tried, what it does, and what you want/expect instead? Passing a keymap as an arg to a function isn't related to using any packages, modes, or hooks. Please keep it simple.

Comment: Related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61225

Comment: Could the discussion https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/issues/301 be relevant?  I don't use `evil-mode` but the discussion suggests to me that you need to run some update function, such as `evil-normalize-maps`, after `evil-define-key`.